# Triggering ASP.Net functions from JS and viceversa

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I was thinking to my self if there is a better implementation to my approach in triggering functions from JavaScript to ASP.Net and viceversa.

**Run JS code from ASP.Net**

1. Create asp.net hidden value that will keep information of what
   action was done. (Eg. `id = hiddenFunctionality`)
2. Behind ASP.NET code, do the functionality than
   alter the asp.net hidden value `(hiddenFunctionality.value = "AddedUser")` to trigger the correct JS function later on.
3. From the JS aspect create pageLoad() method and within the pageLoad() method
   read the asp.net hidden value `if(document.getElementById('contentPage_hiddenFunctionality').value=="AddedUser"){...}`

**Run ASP.Net code from JS**

1. Create a div that hides it's content yet leaves the ASP.Net elements still clickable.
2. Insert ASP.Net button within the div. (There should be a work around with the __doPostBack(eventTarget, eventArgument), this would remove the hidden div and ASP.Net button)
3. In JS trigger `<li onclick="trigger('#contentPage_btn');">Click me to trigger ASP.Net function</li>`) run a method to simply trigger click event on the ASP.Net button. `function trigger(x){$(x).click();}`

Passing of data from one side to another can be done with ASP.Net hidden values or query strings.

Comment: Are you referring to ajax updatepanel?

Comment: No, [jQuery AJAX](http://encosia.com/using-jquery-to-directly-call-aspnet-ajax-page-methods/) for running ASP.NET code from JS. For running JS code from ASP.NET, do as row1 mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

To inject JavaScript from ASP you can do [RegisterClientScriptBlock](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.clientscriptmanager.registerclientscriptblock%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
Type myType = this.GetType();
if (!ClientScript.IsClientScriptBlockRegistered(someType, "_FROMASP"))
{
    string script = "alert('FROM ASP!');";
    ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(someType, "FROMASP", script, true);
}
```

I think you are on the right track if you want to run ASP code from JS and not use AJAX. I normally use a hidden field with `__doPostBack` to pass messages rather than a DIV.